# Client side interceptor and external load balancing architecture

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, architecture

I'm implementing a new application at our company and I'm looking for ways to do clustering. There are two types of architectures available as per the jboss documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/cluster.concepts.chapt.html).

1. Client side interceptor
2. External Load balancing

Question 1: In client side interceptor architecture. The client has the proxy object and it knows which server to route the messages to. Who is the **client** here? I know the java script/HTML cannot hold the proxy object. Is it a spring/servlet layer in front of the nodes?

Question 2: Does the external load balancer know anything about the code and the services that the nodes can contain Or it just uses algorithm to delegate the request to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 1 -** The client, is Remote EJB dynamic proxies and/or application client containers (desktop apps)

**For 2** - the external load balancer doesn't know anything about the code.
(I see this solution in use far more than the scenario in question 1)

there are many ways to configure clustering, depending on your load balancing and fault-tolerance goals.  For Example you can load balance between application servers that are not clustered.  Less fault-tolerance, faster performance, because there is no session replication.

**Here is a bit more detail on number 1.**

Suppose in question 1 that I have an distributed application.  Say a Web App and EJBs running on a application server, and i wish to call some EJBs of another application server.

When you call a remote EJB the application server generates a class which is transfered to the calling server.  This is the dynamic proxy, it contains all the network communications stuff.

Across the application server market place we usually see two forms of configuration, (1) a dynamic proxy class that is aware of the cluster and will call other nodes, (2) a CORBA URL with a list of node i.e. corbaloc::nodeA.host.com,nodeB.host.com/...

**Here is a bit more detail on number 2.**

The second case is typically where we are providing HTTP based services, WebUI, REST, SOAP, etc. to callers in the 'outside' world.

Apache HTTPD with mod_jk plugin is an example in the JBoss docs [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Using+mod_jk+with+JBoss+AS7)

The requests can be sent to different servers to address load or failure.  the HTTP sessions object is replicated between the nodes.  (JGroups library in JBoss handles this,  IP Multicast is also a common technique)

So the load balancer / reverse proxy doesn't need to know about the code it just knows about URLs to forward requests to, the application servers in the cluster collaborate for session information.

Comment: So, to understand the point 1 correctly above. you are saying that the 'client side interceptor' is used when one of the application needs to call another application and which does not involve (REST or other html request) ?

Comment: and use the external load balancer when there is a need for the html/external world to invoke the server?

Comment: If using Load balancing without session replication, would it be a sticky a session, which means that the request from a client always goes to the load balanced server where it went first?

Comment: yes the stick session keeps the HTTP session 'stuck' to one node.  Usually when i design these I use the sticky session even if i have session replication.  It is a 'safe' setting.  If i have stateless web resources (no HTTP sessions) then turning off sticky sessions can give a little performance boost under peak load.

Comment: Note: that by 'external' i mean internal web users to.